# Writing nested records from Java dataflow to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have some objects with nested fields that I want to write from my dataflow job into a BigQuery table. I understand how to create the table schema, but I don't see how to create a [TableRow](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableRow.html) with nested fields.

The TableRow object is just a list of [TableCell](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableCell.html) objects, which appear to be String,Object key-value pairs. How can I build a nested object this way? Can the value of a TableCell be a TableRow?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please show a concrete example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: This should be useful: https://sookocheff.com/post/bigquery/writing-repeated-bigquery-records/

Comment: @ElliottBrossard thanks, that does help, if only by implication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link shared by @ElliotBrossard points towards a solution:
https://sookocheff.com/post/bigquery/writing-repeated-bigquery-records/

Just as a repeated field is represented using a `List<TableRow>`, a nested field is represented using a `TableRow` where some of the field values are themselves `TableRow` objects.